# Issue with incorrect dates displayed in line chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a line chart for simple forecasting, and I'm having problems with the last data point displayed with incorrect date.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/5pztkwra/ ---
Sample Image: [Burn-up forecasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOXft.png)

I.e. the last point for the blue and orange lines should be displayed as 06-Jul-20, and instead is showing  11-Jul-20.

In line 170 I've added 5 days to the last date to extend the length of the X axis using `endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 5);`
This is an attempt to add additional space in the chart for the dotted "trend" line and blue line to meet.

This additional 5 days seems to be causing the issue. Any ideas how this could be resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the `setDate` function changes the data element, so that the last data is with date `11-Jul-20`.
It can be fixed by using a new variable to calculate the `endDate` for the x domain.

```
let newEndDate = new Date(endDate)
newEndDate.setDate(newEndDate.getDate() + 5); // adding more time at the end of the X axix
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

  pre {display:none;}

  /* Basic Styling with CSS */
  body {
    font: 15px sans-serif;
    color: #444444;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  /* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ffab00;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }
  
    .line2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #398fff;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }

  .reg {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 3;
  }

  /* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
  .dot {
      fill: #ffab00;
      stroke: #fff;
  }
  
   .dot2 {
      fill: #398fff;
      stroke: #fff;
  }
  
    /* Styling the title*/
  div.title {
      text-align: center;
      font: 20px sans-serif;
      padding-top: 20px;
  }

    /* Styling text in popup box*/
  div.tooltip {
  color:white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
  font: 15px sans-serif;
  background: #ffab00;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
  }

  div.tooltip2 {
  color:white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
  font: 15px sans-serif;
  background: #398fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>

  <pre id="data">
      ,date,closed,created
      25/06/2020,25-Jun-20,0,40
      26/06/2020,26-Jun-20,4,40
      28/06/2020,28-Jun-20,8,40
      29/06/2020,29-Jun-20,12,43
      01/07/2020,01-Jul-20,17,43
      03/07/2020,03-Jul-20,22,44
      04/07/2020,04-Jul-20,25,44
      06/07/2020,06-Jul-20,31,44 
  </pre>
  <div class="title"> Burn-up chart </div>

  <div>
    <!-- Load in the d3 and simple-statistics library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/simple-statistics@2.0.0-beta3/dist/simple-statistics.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50},
          width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right - 20,
          height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom -80;
          
      var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
      var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%a %d %b");

      // define x y axis
      var x = d3.time.scale()
          .range([0, width]);

      var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d %b"));

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left");

      var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
          .attr("class", "tooltip")
          .style("opacity", 0);
      
      var div2 = d3.select("body").append("div")
          .attr("class", "tooltip2")
          .style("opacity", 0);

      // d3's line generator
      var line = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.closed); })
          .interpolate("monotone");
          
      var line2 = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.created); })
          .interpolate("monotone");


      // Add the SVG to the page
      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
          
        
        // get dataset
        var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("#data").text() );        
                data.forEach(function (d) {
                if (d.closed){ 
                d.date = d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                d.closed = +d.closed;
                d.created = +d.created;
            }});
            data.pop(); //remove last "undefined" row
            //console.log(data);
                
        // Get min and max for X axis range
        var startDate = d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.date; });
        var endDate = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.date; });
        
        //
        //
        let newEndDate = new Date(endDate)
        newEndDate.setDate(newEndDate.getDate() + 5); // adding more time at the end of the X axix
        //
        //
        
        //console.log(startDate.toString());
        //console.log(endDate.toString());   
        //console.log(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.closed; }));
        //console.log(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.closed; }));
        
        // Get min and max for Y axis range
        var  arr= [];
        arr.push(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.closed; }));
        arr.push(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.created; })); 
        arr.push(d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.closed; }));  
        arr.push(d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.created; })); 
        //console.log(arr);
        
        // define how long the axis are
        x.domain([startDate,newEndDate]);
        y.domain(d3.extent(arr));

        // Derive a linear regression
        var regression = ss.linearRegression(data.map(function(d) {
          return [+d.date, d.closed];
        }));
        var lin = ss.linearRegressionLine(regression);
        
        // Create a line based on the beginning and endpoints of that range
        var lindata = x.domain().map(function(x) {
          return {
            date: new Date(x),
            closed: lin(+x)
          };
        });
              

        // Call the x axis in a group tag
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor","end")
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(-45)');

        // Call the y axis in a group tag
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Story Count");

        // Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator 
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
        
        // same for the second line 
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line2")
            .attr("d", line2);

        // and for the doted "trend" line
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(lindata)
            .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
            .attr("class", "reg")
            .attr("d", line);

        // Appends a circle for each datapoint line 1
        svg.selectAll(".dot")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
            .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.closed); })
            .attr("r", 5)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
               div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
               div.html(d.closed + " items - " + dateFormat(d.date))
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
               div.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .style("opacity", 0);           
                });
            
            // Appends a circle for each datapoint line 2
        svg.selectAll(".dot2")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
            .attr("class", "dot2") // Assign a class for styling
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.created); })
            .attr("r", 5)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
               div2.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
               div2.html(d.created + " items - " + dateFormat(d.date))
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
               div2.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .style("opacity", 0);           
                });
    </script>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58q7b1my/2/)

Comment: Brilliant! 


Thanks soundquiet :) .  --   
 



I've now added an additional doted line to visualise where the lines meet - All coming along nicely (https://jsfiddle.net/abpe3L80/)